# feedforward torque?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It would be very useful to be able to apply a feedforward torque in addition to PID control:
torque = kp x positionerror + kv x velocityerror + ki x integratederror + torqueff
torqueff could be a constant or have a trajectory, as does desired position and velocity.

I see in the list of robot_mechanism_controllers 
[http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot\_mechanism\_controllers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot%5C_mechanism%5C_controllers)
JointEffortController mode, which supports torque control but does not include PID control, and
JointTrajectoryActionController and JointPostionController which support PID control but not feedforward torques.
Is there a controller that supports both?

I see there used to be an ArmDynamicsController that looks like it had the right properties.
Google arm_dynamics_controller.cpp

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/856/feedforward-torque?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Filed a ticket for this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/785/feedforward-torque-controller

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-07-23**:
That's a duplicate of issue 446: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/446